# Redirecting Enrage Damage

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Shaman en-Kor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShaman%20en-Kor%5d) and creature with Enrage (For this instance lets says it's a 0/2 with Enrage). An opponent casts a spell which would deal 2 damage to all creatures.
I used the Shaman's (0) redirect ability *twice* to direct the damage to my Enrage-Creature. Would enrage...:

1. ... Enrage trigger just once since all damage is dealt to it at once
2. ... Enrage trigger twice because of damage from two different sources.
3. ... Enrage trigger twice because of damage from the spell, then the triggered ability of the shaman hits it?- And can you respond with an instant in-between the damage?
4. ... Enrage trigger three times total. Once from the spell damage, then twice more since the Shaman's ability redirected two instances?

I've found this question/answer but it skirts around the answer I am looking for:
[What's the timing on Warrior en-Kor's damage redirection?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45466/whats-the-timing-on-warrior-en-kors-damage-redirection)

Comment: In this scenario are you activating the Shaman's ability once or twice? In other words, are you redirecting one point of damage, or both?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Twice, updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Enrage triggered ability only triggers once.**

An instruction like "[This card] deals 2 damage to each creature" deals all of its damage simultaneously in a single damage-dealing event. The Shaman's redirection effects modify that event to deal 4 damage to the creature with enrage and 0 to the Shaman, but the result is still just one event, which only triggers the Enrage ability once.